# Is it more efficient to use getters or assign them to a variable?

Tags: java, optimization

In the below scenario, all 3 `getXxxxx()` methods simple return a property of that class with no additional processing.

**Is it more efficient for me to assign them to a temporary variable like I've done with `workLimit`, or should I just use the getter like I did with `getCurrentWork()`?**

```
    int x = 0;
    int workLimit = entity.getCurrentWorkLimit();
    JobSet jobSet;
    JobSetQueue queue = workflowProcess.getQueue();
    while (x < workLimit && (jobSet = queue.poll()) != null) {
        getCurrentWork().addLast(jobSet);
    }
```

Comment: I doubt very much that it makes any real difference, but the best way to find out is to do a simple test (time it).

Comment: Efficient in what aspect ?

Comment: If possible, the JVM will inline it anyway.

Comment: This isn't where you're losing performance. Besides, getters are prime candidates for JIT inlining. If this one isn't, the difference will be equivalent to statistical noise.

Comment: Stop micro-optimizing. Rather than trying to shave that 0.1% off of the run-time, rather focus on finding that inefficiency that's slowing your program down by 60%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VM optimizes access to simple getters itself - but in fact you usually shouldn't care about it. Therefore, I would usually optimize code for readibility / maintainability instead of performance. Performance optimizations should be based on facts, not assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming getCurrentWork() is just returning a variable itself, then the performance will be the same. I think that having the extra variable sometimes makes the code easier to read/scan especially when you have lots of them.  In thise case, I'd probably just use the getter.

Answer (score 0):

You are in essence buying one less stack operation, this is a micro-optimization and as such is almost completely useless, unless you are writing a real-time system.

At the end of the day, **profile profile profile**

Comment: I would bet that, even on the realest (?) of real-time system, it still won't make a big enough difference to prefer one over the other.